# Problem with BROWSEINFO to get select directory on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I try to get a directory selected by user.  My code runs well on windows 7 but crash on windows 10. The code snippet is as follows. The IDE is Visual Studio 2010, and I use MFC to develop this program on windows 7.

```
    // On click a button 
    CString cstrSnapPicPath = g_pSingleton->GetSnapPicPath();  //  The default path is cstrSnapPicPath, such as "C:\Program Files (x86)\AAA BBB\SnapPicture\"
    BROWSEINFO bi;    
    TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];
    bi.hwndOwner = this->m_hWnd;  
    bi.pidlRoot = NULL;  
    bi.lParam = (LPARAM)(cstrSnapPicPath.GetString());
    bi.pszDisplayName = _T(""); 
    bi.lpszTitle = _T("");
    bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;  
    bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc;  
    bi.iImage = 0;

    LPITEMIDLIST pIDList = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);  // The program just crash here when user select a directory , then click Ok on windows 10, but works fine on windows 7.
    if (pIDList)
    {
        ....
    }
```

The BrowseCallbackProc is as follow:

```
int CALLBACK BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,LPARAM lParam,LPARAM lpData)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case BFFM_INITIALIZED:
        {
            ::SendMessage(hwnd,BFFM_SETSELECTION,TRUE,(LPARAM)(LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)lpData);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` prior to calling `SHBrowseForFolder`?

Comment: What kind of crash exactly? What is the actual error message? What does your `BrowseCallbackProc` look like?

Comment: `pszDisplayName` should be writable. For example `bi.pszDisplayName = Buffer;`

Comment: I assign the `pszDisplayName` to a writable buffer, and it works! But, why the programm not crash  when run on windows 7 if it need to be writable .

Comment: A program that's invalid is not required to exhibit any particular behavior.

Comment: This won't succeed in Windows 7 either, at least not consistently. If `pszDisplayName` is `const* char/wchar_t` then the function will still attempt to write to it, because the function is not aware of any problems up to that point. What happens after that is undefined behavior. Note, if you click cancel on folder dialog then no attempt is made to write to buffer, and no error.